# Constrained endpoint on specific user

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to create a PowerShell endpoint constraint that restricts an user to only execute the functions in a custom module I made.

The first thing I did is `import-module mymodule.psm1` which allows me to run my modules fine withing my host system.

Then the following PS command creates the configuration file for the endpoint which allows the functions inside the brackets to be the only functions the user gets to execute.

```
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -VisibleFunctions('Get-Command','Get-Info', 'CreateAD-User','Generate-Html','Change-Logon') -LanguageMode ‘ConstrainedLanguage’ –SessionType ‘RestrictedRemoteServer’ –Path ‘c:\test\helpdesk.pssc’
```

Then I register the endpoint with

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration –Name ‘HelpDesk’ -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI –Path ‘c:\test\helpdesk.pssc’
```

and selected which user I want allow to have these constrains once the `SecurityDescriptorUI` pops up. Once I log into the user that I set up the constrains for with

```
Enter-PSSession -computername SRV1-AD -Credential $credential -ConfigurationName HelpDesk
```

These are the allowed cmdlets / functions that the user is allowed to execute. These are the default required cmdlets to allow remote connections into a system.

[image]

How can I allow my custom module to be the only functions the endpoint allows users to execute? or How can I import my module into configuration file so it executes every time the HelpDesk end point configuration is used. I know that in the configuration file there's a line to import modules but Import-Module is not actually a module an example of a module would be ActiveDirectory, if I'm able to find what module import-module is a part of I think I should be able to do a quick and dirty work around for this.

**UPDATE**

A dirty solution I found for this was to enter into the user's session and disable all cmdlets / functions except the ones I want to allowed for example `import-module` & `Get-Command` with import-module I can manually import my custom module and my functions will be the only ones visible to user. But this is not a perfect solution because this means that I would need to download my module into every system I want this to take effect and it's no longer a one to many solution. The ideal solution is to have my module locally stored, enter into a session with the registered end point and have my module already imported into the users account.

```
Enter-PSSession -computername SRV1-AD -Credential $credential -ConfigurationName HelpDesk
```

**Further Update**

User @prasoon-karunan-v suggested I used `-ScriptsToProcess` & `FunctionDefinitions` to import the module so I used the following command

```
New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -VisibleFunctions('Get-Command','Get-Info', 'CreateAD-User','Generate-Html','Change-Logon') -LanguageMode ‘ConstrainedLanguage’ –SessionType ‘RestrictedRemoteServer’ –Path ‘.\EndPoint.pssc’ -ScriptsToProcess C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Modules\ImportM.psm1
```

In the configuration file I also set the functions I want to use like so

```
# Functions defined in this session configuration
FunctionDefinitions = 'Get-Command','Get-Info', 'CreateAD-User','Generate-Html','Change-Logon'
```

When I tried to establish a session it would throw the following error

[image: Error1]

Then I thought maybe it's not working because were not telling the command to import anything were just pointing to the module file, so maybe I need to create a small script that imports the module then add it the configuration file. So that's exactly what I did I created a small script with just, 
import-module C:\Modules\ImportM.psm1 and then I went over to the .pssc 
file and added this script to the `ScriptsToProcess` but I get the following error after I try to establish a session to the constrained endpoint.

[image: Error]

**Language Mode** is set to

```
LanguageMode = 'RestrictedLanguage'
```

Comment: So by this: 'The ideal solution is to have my module locally stored...',  You are saying, you want to put this module on a file share and any host in your enterprise be able to reference it?   Potentially then, that means you'd have to modify each user's $profile to dot source to that share, and have to deal with scenarios when that share would be offline/unavailable when a user starts their host and attempts to use your module.

Comment: I don't know if I phased that correctly, I don't want to use a share or for the configuration to be permanent, when you use `-ConfigurationName HelpDesk` while login into a session the constraint or restrictions execute if you don't use `-ConfigurationName HelpDesk` the users profile will be a regular profile. @postanote

Comment: I'd suggest [reading through this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/jea/role-capabilities).  Why aren't you using `JEA`?

Comment: I can't use JEA I'm on powershell 4 @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: @Katz Can you upgrade to PS V5.1? Or is that a deal breaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `-ScriptsToProcess` parameter, which can be used to import your custom module.

See below as well.

`Get-Help New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Parameter ScriptsToProcess`

`Get-Help New-PSSessionConfigurationFile -Parameter FunctionDefinitions`

Update:

Be sure about the language mode to use,
see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: so I added my custom module to `ScriptsToProcess` I added it using the absolute path to the module for ex `C:\Modules\module1.psm1` but I can't establish the session with Enter-PSSession once I try to login with `-ConfigurationName HelpDesk` but without it, it works fine. I will update my question and I will add an image of the error.

Comment: I updated the question. Let me know if you need more info Thanks!

Comment: @Katz - Updated my answer